# Electrostatic, potential

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

I tried to search the answer of this question on Google also that How much charge is exchanged between the atmosphere and earth's surface everyday . But I didn't get answer of this question .any one who know about it?

Comment: Please write a more descriptive title to your post.  It doesn't say anything about your question, so many people won't read the post.

Comment: Current is 1800 A. Have a look at this: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_09.html